# Where did I go wrong computing the cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

> If $u=(-2,0,\sqrt2)$ and $v=(0,-4,-\sqrt2)$, then $u\times v=(2\sqrt2,-\sqrt2,8)$.

I got $(4 \sqrt2, 2\sqrt2,0)$ for the cross product but the answer is saying I'm wrong and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that
$$ (-2,0,\sqrt{2}) \times (0,-4,-\sqrt{2}) = (4\sqrt{2}, -2\sqrt{2}, 8) \,. $$
Since you have not written out your calculation, there is no way for us to know where you got it wrong.

Comment: I realized where i went wrong with the 8 I accidentally put 0 in the question when I had got 8 in my working out it was just the first part of the vector confusing me how in the answer sheet its 2root2 but I got 4root2